# When using an X-type multicolumn, the width is not well calculated

Tags: tabularx, multicolumn

I have a tabularx with three columns, and in some rows I need to put two columns together and adjust them using type X.
The problem is that when I join columns together using X the margin of this one seems to be smaller than the one of the table.(in the image you can see)

[image: multicolumnX]

How can I fix this?

The code on the table looks something like this:

```
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lcX}\toprule
    Name                               & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Clave C.U.}\\\midrule
    Version                            & \multicolumn{2}{X}{1.0}\\\midrule
    Autors                             & \multicolumn{2}{X}{Very long text...}\\\midrule
    Sequence                           & Step & Action \\\midrule
    ...
  \end{tabularx}
```

Comment: Welcome! What's the reason for declaring three columns and then always spanning the last two?

Comment: @egreg Oh, it's not in every case, I think I need to modify the sample code.

Comment: @urely Take a look at my answer and tell we what should be different

Answer (score 1):

**Example 1 - using tabularx**

Defining a new column type that spans two X-columns plus the `\tabcolsep`s between the columns, solves your problem.

The only deviation from your tabular is that column 2 is a centred `X` column, not a `c` column.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{D}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr 2\hsize+2\tabcolsep}X}

%\multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr 2\hsize+2\tabcolsep}X

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}lCX@{}}

\toprule
    Name            & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Clave C.U.}     \\ \midrule
    Version         & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{1.0}\\\midrule
    Autors          & \multicolumn{2}{D@{}}{Very long text, but how long do 
                                            you want it to be. since you use
                                            an X column, problably more than 
                                            one line}        \\ \midrule
    Something other & that do & not span the last two columns\\ \midrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

**Example 2 - using tabular**

In example 2, the width of column 1 and column 2 is set to the length of the longest text in the columns. You have to copy the text into the to `\setlength` commands. The width of the columns are used to calculate the with of columns 3, which is the line width, minus the width of columns 1 and 2 and the relevant space between the columns.

I have defined the spanned paragraph column (`T`) base on the same logic. It is not necessary to define new column types, but it is convenient.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}

\newcolumntype{P}{p{\dimexpr(\linewidth-(\ColOneWidth+\ColTwoWidth+4\tabcolsep))\relax}}
\newcolumntype{T}{p{\dimexpr(\linewidth-(\ColOneWidth+2\tabcolsep))\relax}}

\newlength{\ColOneWidth}
\newlength{\ColTwoWidth}

\settowidth{\ColOneWidth}{Something totally different}  % Add the longest text in col1
\settowidth{\ColTwoWidth}{that do not}                  % Add the longest text in col2

\begin{document}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}lcP@{}}

\toprule
Name                         & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Clave C.U.}\\\midrule
Version                      & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{1.0}\\\midrule
Autors                       & \multicolumn{2}{T@{}}{Very long text, but how long do you want it to be. since you use an X column, problably more than a line}\\\midrule
Something totally different & that do not & span the last two nice columns, which has to be so wide that you have a linebreak\\ \midrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You understood me pretty well. But in your answer for example if you remove the `\centering` you will notice how the text jumps to the next line before reaching the limit of the table, that's the problem.

Comment: Yes, I suppose all that can be solved using the `p{}` type, but the width would have to be calculated manually and as there are many tables I find it impractical.

Comment: @urely See if my last update of the code solves your problem

Comment: I am more convinced by the second solution, but I don't like the fact that the width is specified, i.e. if I change the margins or the orientation of the page the given widths would have to be changed.

Comment: @urely It will not always be necessary to change the fixed width columns, because the combination of `tabular*` and `@{\extracosep{\fill}}` will add or remove space between the columns to adjust to the margin width. However, it will not be able to compensate for major margin changes. In such case, you need columns calculated relative to the margins.

Comment: @urely Please, have a look at my updated example 2, using `tabular` and calculated columns.